# Is it possible to use constructor of a class in Java and declare it as a datatype in another class?

Tags: java, constructor

If I have a constructor called Point inside class Point:

```
public Point(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y; 
}
```

How can I use it another class called Square and initialize the points. For example, I want to initialize 4 points in a square. How can I do that?

I don't know if that makes sense. But, I tried my best... ask me questions so that I can explain better.

Comment: Can you ask the question better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to have a `Square` with for points, make them attributes:

```
class Square {
    Point p1, p2, p3, p4;
    public Square() {
      p1 = new Point(0,0);
      p2 = new Point(0,0);
      p3 = new Point(0,0);
      p4 = new Point(0,0);
    }
}
```

Of course, there are a zillion other ways of defining and using this. It will depend primarily on your class / program design what you should choose.

Comment: Point p1, p2, p3, p4; - That's what I was looking for. Didn't know this was possible.

Comment: Don't you have to include (x,y) coordinates inside the constructor as arguments?

Comment: @Appsheriff if you want, you can create all kinds of constructors. You don't **have** to include them, you can. All depends on the design you are making.

Answer (score 5):

Your Square class should have a constructor like this:

```
public Square(Point p1, Point p2, Point p3, Point p4) {
        this.p1 = p1;
        this.p2 = p2;
        this.p3 = p3;
        this.p4 = p4;
}
```

You initialize your Square like this:

```
Square s = new Square(new Point(1,1), new Point(2,2), new Point(3,3), new Point(4,4));
```

Comment: That is not a square (assuming Cartesian plane). Better initialize the square with one point (position) and size, and compute the other 3 points in the constructor.

Comment: +1 The only problem with this approach is that you can have any four vertex shape, not just a square. (You have provided a good example of how easy it is to create something which is not a square ;)

Comment: I realize that, it was more of an answer to the question asked in the title.

Answer (score 2):

I do not see the problem. Your `Square` would simply have four members of type `Point` which would be initialized using the usual `new`-syntax:

```
class Square {
    Point topLeft;

    public Square() {
        topLeft = new Point(0,0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
public Shape(Point... points) {
    this.points = points;
}
```

or

```
public Quadrilateral(Point p1, Point p2, Point p3, Point p4) {
    this.p1 = p1;
    this.p2 = p2;
    this.p3 = p3;
    this.p4 = p4;
}
```

or

```
public Square(double x, double y, double size) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.size = size;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I follow, but if you have a constructor like you say, you can simply call `new Point(10.0, 15.0)` to create a point at the designated coordiantes.

Maybe it's something like this that you are after?

```
class Square {
    private Point upperLeftCorner;
    private Point upperRightCorner;
    private Point lowerLeftCorner;
    private Point lowerRightCorner;

    public Square(double x, double y, double size) {
        upperLeftCorner = new Point(x, y);
        lowerLeftCorner = new Point(x, y+size);
        upperRightCorner = new Point(x+size, y);
        lowerRightCorner = new Point(x+size, y+size);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

`java GeoTest 
[{0.0,0.0}, {0.0,10.0}, {10.0,10.0}, {10.0,0.0}]`

Code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class GeoTest{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(new Square(new Point(0,0), new Point(10,10)).getCourners()));
    }
}
class Point{
    private double x;
    private double y;
    public Point(double x, double y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y; 
    }
    public String toString(){
        return new String("{"+x+","+y+"}");
    }
    public double getX(){
        return x;
    }
    public double getY(){
        return y;
    }
}

class Square {
    private Point lowerLeft;
    private Point upperRight;
    /**
     * Assuming x & y axis as follows: 
     * Lower left corner (x,y):0,0 -> upper right corner (x,y): n,n where n > 0
     */
    public Square(Point lowerLeft, Point upperRight){
        this.lowerLeft = lowerLeft;
        this.upperRight = upperRight;
    }
    public Point[] getCourners(){
        return new Point[]{lowerLeft, new Point(lowerLeft.getX(),upperRight.getY()),upperRight, new Point(upperRight.getX(), lowerLeft.getY())};
    }
}
```